# Unknown Configuration Setting for Emmet in vscode Extensions

Tags: vscode-extensions

I can't search the "emmet" on the settings. I want to add the emmet extension to my project so that I can work faster with the help of emmet. I think I accidentally disabled or removed Emmet when I tried `ctrl shift p` and typed "Developer: running extension".
Then on the settings.json when I tried adding emmet, it shows "Unknown Configuration Setting". I tried re-installing Vs code; restarting vs code again; uninstalled all my extensions.

```
  "emmet.showSuggestionsAsSnippets": true,
  "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "html"
  }
```

here is some code of my settings.json

```
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
  "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
  "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
  "explorer.fileNesting.enabled": true,
  "tabnine.experimentalAutoImports": true,
  "editor.minimap.autohide": true,
  "workbench.editorAssociations": {
    "*.apk": "default",
    "*.exe": "default",
    "*.bat": "default"
  },
  "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false,
  "todohighlight.isEnable": true,
  "emmet.showSuggestionsAsSnippets": true,
  "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "html"
  },
  "files.associations": {
    "*html": "html",
    "*njk": "html"
  },
  "auto-rename-tag.activationOnLanguage": [
    "*"
  ],
  "bookmarks.label.suggestion": "useWhenSelected",
  "bookmarks.saveBookmarksInProject": true
```

Still on the vs code doesn't autocomple when i type "!" then `Tab` or `ctrl + space`.

It should Autocomple when i type "!" then `Tab` or `ctrl + space`. And when i search on the setting "emmet" it shows "No setting Found"

Comment: If you open the page of that extension in VS Code, you should be able to see what settings are offered under "FEATURE CONTRIBUTIONS" section. If none of the extensions you installed have those `emmet.*` settings, you know what's wrong.

Comment: In your extensions sidebar input, enter `@builtin emmet`.  Does it show `emmet` there and is it enabled?

Comment: Ohhh It shows after typing `@builtin emmet` on the sidebar.
I accendentally disabled it. Lol.
Thanks for the Help